# Highlight building on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, qgis

Need some advise on how can I draw a outline of a particular block?

I have attached image of Singapore that is captured using OneMap, I have drawn a red outline at Blk 156, how can I do that in Leaflet or how can I retrieve the polygon coordinate of Blk 156 in OneMap API? I am currently using Leaflet and loading OneMap. I actually want to just overlay another polygon to highlight the area that user have search. Let's say user search for Blk 156, I would like to highlight the Blk 156. 
Sorry if I am not clear on my question.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution and just stumbled across wrld.js which has building highlighting although 3d. Maybe it helps: https://www.wrld3d.com/wrld.js/latest/docs/examples/adding-a-building-highlight/